# ExtJS: How can we create a simple header which contains a logo and some menu options?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using Sencha Architech , very new.

I have a header Panel. But i have no idea how to add some img, some menu options into it?
Do we need to add innerHTML to achieve it?

How can we do that like 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/grid

the header and have a search box

Comment: I guess that your header is normal Ext.panel.Panel
so you can easy add toolbar with buttons.
Images something like 
items: 
[{
    xtype: "panel",
    html: "<img ..."
}]

And searchbox would be simple input in right place flaoting to the right.

Comment: so that mean we have to add all the html element into html property?

Comment: In html only images Others with Extjs xtypes

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the header in two ways:

1. using the panel's `title` and `tools` properties. In the `title` you can add text and in the `tools` you can define icons with functionality.
   For example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    (...)
    title: 'Title text',    
    tools: [{ 
        type: 'refresh',
        handler: function (event, toolEl, owner, tool) {
            console.log('refresh button clicked', event, toolEl, owner, tool);
        }
    },{ 
        type: 'help',
        handler: function (event, toolEl, owner, tool) {
            console.log('refresh button clicked', event, toolEl, owner, tool);
        }
    },{ 
        type: 'your-own-button',
        handler: function (event, toolEl, owner, tool) {
            console.log('your-own-button clicked, img needs to be set in css -> x-tool-your-own-button');
        }
    }],
    (...)
});
```

1. using the panel's `header` propery. With it you need to define a new inner header panel. you can use the `title`, `titlePosition`, `tools` and `items` properties inside the `header` definition.
   For example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    (...)
    header: {
        xtype:'header',
        title: 'Title text',
        titlePosition: 0,
        tools: [{ 
            type: 'refresh',
            handler: function (event, toolEl, owner, tool) {
                console.log('refresh button clicked', event, toolEl, owner, tool);
            }
        },{ 
            type: 'help',
            handler: function (event, toolEl, owner, tool) {
                console.log('refresh button clicked', event, toolEl, owner, tool);
            }
        },{ 
            type: 'your-own-button',
            handler: function (event, toolEl, owner, tool) {
                console.log('your-own-button clicked, img needs to be set in css -> x-tool-your-own-button');
            }
        }],
        items:[{
            xtype:'textfield',
            name:'testTextfield',
            fieldLabel:'Test',
            labelWidth: 30,
            width: 100          
        }]
    },
    (...)
});
```